# Store Hostname in a variable

Tags: powershell

When I go to PowerShell and type there:

```
PS> Hostname
```

I get the name of the current machine - which is ok (the name is: my_host)
My question is, how can I store this value into a variable?

I have this query (backup DB):

```
$query = "BACKUP DATABASE [my_db] TO  DISK = N'\\${Hostname}\Backup\test\DB\my_db.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'my_db Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION"
```

As you can see, I inserted there the variable `$Hostname`, but it doesn't work like that.

As I mentioned, my Hostname is my_host,
so this is the expected result:

```
$query = "BACKUP DATABASE [my_db] TO  DISK = N'\\my_host\Backup\test\DB\my_db.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'my_db Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION"
```

How can I do it?

BTW, I know that it doesn't work, because when I run this command, it fails:

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Username user -Password 12345 -ErrorAction Stop -ServerInstance my-db-server -Database master -Query ${query} -QueryTimeout 0 -OutputSqlErrors 1
```

Comment: `$hostname = [Net.Dns]::GetHostName()`

Comment: @Bill_Stewart If you make this an answer I'd vote for it but please add more info on when this could not work

Comment: What do you mean by "when this could not work"? I'm not aware of any circumstances where it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Hostname command in your variable with syntax $(Hostname). Your command will work like you expect in this format:

```
$query ="BACKUP DATABASE [my_db] TO  DISK = N'\\$(Hostname)\Backup\test\DB\my_db.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'my_db Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION"
```

Answer (score 2):

`hostname` is actually `hostname.exe`, i.e. it's not a native command that is interpreted by the shell, but an external command that is invoked.

You can assign the output to an variable as usual:

```
$hostname = hostname.exe
```

Then you can build the query string like this

```
$query ="BACKUP DATABASE [my_db] TO  DISK = N'\\$hostname\Backup\test\DB\my_db.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'my_db Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION"
```

or with the `-f` operator

```
$query = "BACKUP DATABASE [my_db] TO  DISK = N'\\{0}\Backup\test\DB\my_db.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'my_db Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION" -f $Hostname
```

If you want to use `hostname.exe` without a helper variable you can use a subexpression `$()`.

```
$query = "BACKUP DATABASE [my_db] TO  DISK = N'\\$(hostname.exe)\Backup\test\DB\my_db.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'my_db Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION"
```

Your example with `${hostname}` equals `$hostname` which is an empty variable and does not call `hostname.exe`.

However, there are various ways to get the hostname without calling an external command, for instance:

Environment variable: `$env:COMPUTERNAME`

WMI Class: `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_ComputerSystem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

You can use both examples as shown before.

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you could use the native `PowerShell` environment variable `$env:COMPUTERNAME`. So one way is:

```
$query ="BACKUP DATABASE [my_db] TO  DISK = N'\\${$env:COMPUTERNAME}\Backup\test\DB\my_db.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'my_db Database Backup', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD, COMPRESSION"
```

---

**Sidenote** - `-Query ${query}` can be simplified to `-Query $query`. Curly brackets make sense when you would refer to an incorrect variable otherwise. Example below.

```
$a = "Easy as "
Write-Host "$aabc"    # looks for variable $aabc
Write-Host "${a}abc"  # looks for variable $a, then prints abc
```

Comment: `hostname` is an executable in `system32` (`C:\Windows\System32\HOSTNAME.EXE)`.  What you're referencing is an machine-wide environment variable.

Comment: $Env:COMPUTERNAME appears to be a Windows-only thing. It is not available in PowerShell 6.0.3 on Linux.

Comment: @lit Interesting - thought it would be mapped to the native linux equivalent

Comment: Depends if `/etc/environment` has a `COMPUTERNAME` defined.

Answer (score 0):

this is the shortest way I could figure out:

$hostname = (hostname)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).